# Superscripts and Subscripts with more than 1 letter

Tags: equations, mathtools

I`m trying to input the following formula in latex:

[image]

So far I came up with:

```
$Pr(Classe_i | Objeto) * Pr(Objeto) * IOU^{truth \_pred}= Pr(Classe_i)* IOU^{truth} \_{pred}$
```

But truth and pred end up side by side and not on a stack. How can I fix it?

Comment: What is this supposed to represent?

Comment: You should definitely be writing `_`, not  `\_`, to create subscripts in math mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write

```
\mathrm{IOU}^{\mathrm{truth}}_{\mathrm{pred}}
```

The `\mathrm` makes the letters upright.

Comment: It did work! is there also some trick to make it all be outputed in a single line?

Comment: If you want to have it inline but not broken over lines, you can put it in a box to accomplish that (just search on this site to find an example for this). Since this equation is rather long, I would recommend typesetting it in display mode (e.g. with `\[` and `\]` around it instead of `$` and `$`. However I would recommend you read a beginner's guide to LaTeX and typesetting math in it to learn the basics.

Comment: You'll have issues when using spaces together with `\mathrm`.

Comment: @Werner, depending on what you want to achieve, those "issues" can be regarded a feature. In indices I usually still want math spacing rules to apply, even when I want to use an upright font to indicate that the index denotes a word (like i for initial) rather than a variable (that may be called i), thus `\mathrm` is almost always the right choice for me. You are of course right that one should be aware that this command does not switch to text mode.

Answer (score 4):

If what you're typing is text in math mode, use `\textup` - it ensures its contents is dislpayed as `up`right `text`, even if the prevailing font is not upright, like *italics* (the case within some `theorem` environments). For a super-/sub-script, use `^` and `_`; this will ensure placement high/low to the right of an object:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\Probability}{(}{)}
\newcommand{\Prob}{\Pr\Probability}

\begin{document}

\[
  \Prob{\textup{Class}_i \mid \textup{Object}} \times
    \Prob{\text{Object}} \times
    \textup{IOU}^{\textup{truth}}_{\textup{pred}}
  = \Prob{\textup{Class}_i} \times
    \textup{IOU}^{\textup{truth}}_{\textup{pred}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Never a good advise to use `\text` in this context. If the op uses this in an italic context the output would be italic, which is obviously not correct here. Sadly there is a lot of users who do not know when to use  `\text` and when not to. I would probably have used `\textup `  or even `\textnormal`. Yes this solution works in this case, but does not in all cases

Comment: @daleif: Oh my, I'm switching that to `\textup`, from now on...

Comment: This is a clear case for `\mathrm`.